# How to refresh page after closing dialog form SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, development

I have created a dialog with the following code:

```
function Dialog() {
   var options = {
    url: 'http://mysite/mypage.aspx',
    title: 'My Title',
    allowMaximize: false,
    showClose: true,
    width: 400,
    height: 350,
    dialogReturnValueCallback: RefreshOnDialogClose

  };    
   SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
}
```

this dialog works good and after i click save it refreshes the page, but if i click close or cancel it refreshes the page again.

So I want only when the save button is clicked to refresh page,  not when close or cancel is pressed.

Thanks

Comment: are you using a  function at RefreshOnDialogClose should you post it ?

Comment: No I just wrote it there I don't have any function with that name, perhaps it is in any JS script

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
 var options = {
    url: 'https://sp2013dev/sites/dev/Shared%20Documents/Forms/EditForm.aspx?ID=9',
    title: 'My Title',
    allowMaximize: false,
    showClose: true,
    width: 400,
    height: 350,
    dialogReturnValueCallback: function(result){
        if (result == SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {
            window.location.reload();
        }
        if (result == SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel) {
            //do nothing, modal was closed
        }
    }

  };    
   SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
```

Be default `RefreshOnDialogClose` always reloads.

Answer (score 6):

Try to remove `RefreshOnDialogClose` and set `dialogReturnValueCallback:` to a function, and check in this function the `dialogResult` to refresh on OK only as the following:

```
 dialogReturnValueCallback: function (dialogResult) {
      if (dialogResult == SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {
           SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);
      }
```

Comment: Check also https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/08/13/open-link-via-modal-dialog-sharepoint/